# Negacion de merge en git

Tags: reactjs, git, github

Cree un proyecto de *React* con **create-react-app** desde el ordenador del trabajo y lo subi a mi *Git*... por defecto el push de este no sube al git todas las dependencias instaladas solo sube una parte de los archivos.. luego fui a hacer pull de mi ordenador de casa y pense lo siguiente para hacer el pull en mi ordenador creo otro proyecto con **create-react-app** para tener las dependencias q me faltan y luego hago un pull desde mi repositorio, asi este me actualizara los cambios que hice... comienza a hacerlo pero al final me muestra el siguiente error:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Hay alguna forma de arreglar esto.. o cuando subo un proyecto react a git y lo clono debo hacerlo de una forma especifica?

Comment: No me parece que esto esté muy claro, pero parece que quieres descargar un proyecto de git a otro proyecto de git y mezclarlos. Creo que lo mejor sería que clones el repositorio, entres al directorio e instales las dependencias con un `npm install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El proceso podría ser así:

En **computadora A**:

1. `mkdir test && npx create-react-app test`
2. `cd test`
3. Agregas por única vez el repositorio remoto con `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/test.git`
4. Luego haces cambios en el proyecto.
5. Agregas los archivos a git con `git add .`
6. Haces un commit `git commit -m "Inicio del proyecto"`
7. Actualizas el repositorio remoto con `git push origin master`

En **computadora B**:

- Clonas el repositorio `git clone https://github.com/user/test.git`
- `cd test`
- Descargas las dependencias con `npm install`
- Repites los pasos del 4 al 7.

Luego en **computadora A**:

- Actualizas los cambios realizados en la computadora B con `git pull`
- Repites los pasos del 4 al 7.

Comment: muchas gracias @logico-software muy completa tu respuesta.